Repeated requests via AJAX get slower and slower
Once I kept repeatedly inputting a character in the search box, it is getting slower and slower until it hangs. I wanted to optimize it and make it smoother.
Can you guys help me or give me any advice for what I should do? I am getting the data correctly it just once I tried to search repeatedly without refreshing the page it is getting laggy.
This is my model:
public class TrieNode
    {
        public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> Children { get; set; }
        public bool IsEndOfWord { get; set; }
        public int Popularity { get; set; }

        public TrieNode()
        {
            Titles = new List<string>();
            Children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
        }
    }

This is my service:
public void Insert(string title)
        {
            var node = _trie;
            foreach (var ch in title)
            {
                if (!node.Children.ContainsKey(ch))
                {
                    node.Children[ch] = new TrieNode();
                }
                node = node.Children[ch];
            }

            if (node.Titles != null)
            {
                node.Titles.Add(title);
            }
            else
            {
                node.IsEndOfWord = true;
            }

            if (node.Titles != null && node.Titles.Count >= Threshold)
            {
                ConvertListToTrie(node);
            }
        }

        private void ConvertListToTrie(TrieNode node)
        {
            foreach (var title in node.Titles)
            {
                Insert(title);
            }
            node.Titles = null;
        }

        /* Search to get exact titles and with levenshtein then sort by latest visit first then popularity and titles asc then lastly with levenshtein*/
        public List<(string title, int popularity)> Search(string prefix)
        {
            var node = _trie;
            foreach (var ch in prefix)
            {
                if (!node.Children.ContainsKey(ch))
                {
                    return new List<(string, int)>();
                }
                node = node.Children[ch];
            }
            return GettitlesFromNode(prefix, node);
        }

        private List<(string title, int popularity)> GettitlesFromNode(string prefix, TrieNode node)
        {
            var titles = new List<(string title, int popularity)>();
            if (node.IsEndOfWord)
            {
                titles.Add((prefix, node.Popularity));
            }
            foreach (var child in node.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value.Popularity))
            {
                titles.AddRange(GettitlesFromNode(prefix + child.Key, child.Value));
            }
            return titles;
        }

        public List<(string title, int popularity)> GetSuggestionsWithLevenshtein(string query)
        {
            var exactMatches = Search(query);
            var additionalSuggestions = new List<(string title, int popularity)>();

            if (exactMatches.Count < 10)
            {
                additionalSuggestions = FindSimilarTitles(query)
                    .Select(w => (title: w, popularity: GetPopularityFromTrie(w)))
                    .Where(w => !exactMatches.Any(s => s.title == w.title))
                    .Take(10 - exactMatches.Count)
                    .ToList();
            }

            return exactMatches.Select(s => (s.title, s.popularity))
                    .Concat(additionalSuggestions)
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.popularity)
                    .ThenBy(s => s.title)
                    .ThenBy(s => Levenshtein(query, s.title))
                    .ToList();
        }

        /* Get Popularity and Last Visit of each title */
        private int GetPopularityFromTrie(string title)
        {
            var node = _trie;
            foreach (var ch in title)
            {
                if (!node.Children.ContainsKey(ch))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                node = node.Children[ch];
            }
            return node.IsEndOfWord ? node.Popularity : 0;
        }

        /* Find Titles with levenshtein distance */
        private List<string> FindSimilarTitles(string input)
        {
            var results = new List<string>();
            foreach (var title in GetAllTitles(_trie, ""))
            {
                if (Levenshtein(input, title) <= 2)
                {
                    results.Add(title);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        public List<string> GetAllTitles(TrieNode node, string prefix)
        {
            var titles = new List<string>();
            if (node.IsEndOfWord)
            {
                titles.Add(prefix);
            }
            foreach (var child in node.Children)
            {
                titles.AddRange(GetAllTitles(child.Value, prefix + child.Key));
            }
            return titles;
        }

        private int Levenshtein(string input, string target)
        {
            if (input == target)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (input.Length == 0)
            {
                return target.Length;
            }

            if (target.Length == 0)
            {
                return input.Length;
            }

            int[,] distance = new int[input.Length + 1, target.Length + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length; i++)
            {
                distance[i, 0] = i;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= target.Length; j++)
            {
                distance[0, j] = j;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= target.Length; j++)
                {
                    int cost = input[i - 1] == target[j - 1] ? 0 : 1;

                    distance[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1, distance[i, j - 1] + 1), distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            return distance[input.Length, target.Length];
        }

This is my controller:
static TrieController()
        {
            var titles = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("./assets/titles.txt");

            foreach (var title in titles)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(title, "^[a-z\\s]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    _trieService.Insert(title.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetSuggestions(string title)
        {
            var suggestions = _trieService.GetSuggestionsWithLevenshtein(title)
                               .Select(s => new { title = s.title, popularity = s.popularity });
            return Ok(suggestions.Take(10));
        }

This is the app.js:
let visitedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visitedTitles')) || [];

/* Suggestions */
function getSuggestions()
 {
    const query = $('#search-box').val();
    if (query.length === 0) {
      $('#suggestions').empty();
      return;
    }
  
    $.ajax({
      //url: `http://ec2-3-25-135-98.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/trie/`,
      url: `https://localhost:7223/trie/`,
      data: { title: query },
      success: function (data) {
        displaySuggestions(data);
      }
    });
  
  $('#clear-button').click(function() 
  {
    $('#search-box').val('');
    $('#suggestions').empty();
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
  
  $('#search-box').on('input', function() 
  {
    const query = $(this).val();
    if (query.length > 0) {
      $('#clear-button').show();
    } else {
      $('#clear-button').hide(); 
    }
    getSuggestions();
  });
}

function displaySuggestions(suggestions) 
{
  const suggestionList = $('#suggestions');
  suggestionList.empty();
  
  const sortData = suggestions.map(title => {
    const visitedItem = visitedTitles.find(item => item.title === title.title);
    return {
      ...title,
      visitDate: visitedItem ? visitedItem.date : null 
    };
  });

  sortData.sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA = new Date(a.visitDate);
    const dateB = new Date(b.visitDate);

    if (isNaN(dateA.getTime()) && isNaN(dateB.getTime())) {
      return 0;
    } else if (isNaN(dateA.getTime())) {
      return 1;
    } else if (isNaN(dateB.getTime())) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
    }
  });
  sortData.forEach(suggestion => {
    const isVisited = visitedTitles.some(item => item.title === suggestion.title);

    if (isVisited) 
    {
      const visitedItem = visitedTitles.find(item => item.title === suggestion.title);
      lastVisited = calculateTimeDifference(visitedItem.date);
    }
      
    const suggestionItems = $(
        '<li class="list-group-item border-bottom d-flex btn btn-outline-success" width="200px;">' +
            '<span class="suggestion-title "><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-xs me-3" style="color: #c4c4c4;"></i>' + suggestion.title + '</span>' + 
            '<span class="text-body-tertiary ms-2" style="scale: 0.7;"><i class="fa-duotone fa-solid fa-eye fa-sm me-1"></i>' + suggestion.popularity + '</span>' + 
        '</li>'
    );

    if(isVisited) {
        suggestionItems.addClass('visited');
    }

  suggestionList.append(suggestionItems);
  });
  

  $('#suggestions').on('click', 'li', function () 
  {
      const title = $(this).find('.suggestion-title').text();
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const gmtPlus8Date = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      const formattedDate = gmtPlus8Date.toISOString().slice(0, 19);

      const visitedItem = {
        title: title,
        date: formattedDate
      };
      visitedTitles.push(visitedItem);
      getByName(title);
      visitedTitles.push(title);
      localStorage.setItem('visitedTitles', JSON.stringify(visitedTitles));
      $('#search-box').val('');
      $('#suggestions').empty();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
const debouncedGetSuggestions = debounce(getSuggestions, 300);
  $('#search-box').on('input', debouncedGetSuggestions, function() {
    currentSearchPage = 1;
    getSuggestions();
  });
})


You have nested event handler assignments. You execute this more than once $('#search-box').on('input', function()  - move the $('#clear-button').click(function()  and $('#search-box').on('input', function()  to outside any other function than a page load event handler.

You need to debounce the event so that it only fires Nms after typing ends. It looks like you're trying to do this, but your on() method signature looks wrong, but that would depend on the implementation of the debounce() method that you haven't included. Could you please edit the question to include it. You can also remove all the server-side C# code as it's not relevant to the problem

Also this will fail on an empty localStorage. let visitedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visitedTitles')) || []; instead move the array inside the parse in quotes: let visitedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visitedTitles') || '[]');
